# How can I make a different text based on the user's choices?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game where the user can choose if they play X or O. How do I change the onclick function to display X if they chose X, or O if they chose O?

My code right now doesn't work since it only displays X even if I selected O from the two buttons.

Note: The other boxes don't have a function yet. To see the problem I'm talking about, click the first box on the upper left.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Koulen&family=VT323&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Signika+Negative:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1C2C54;
    color: #D175B7;
    font-family: 'Signika Negative', sans-serif;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    gap: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

.text-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: #4BC3B5;
    padding: 20px;
    
  }
  .grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
}

button {
    padding: 3px 20px;
    background-color: #4BC3B5;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #34a396;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #2c8d82;
    border: 3px solid #124640;
}

button:focus {
    background-color: #2c8d82;
    border: 3px solid #124640;
}

  .score-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 10px;
      width: 300px;
      justify-content: center;
      color: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="text-container">
            <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid1" onclick="clickBox1()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid2" onclick="clickBox2()" ></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid3" onclick="clickBox3()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid4" onclick="clickBox4()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid5" onclick="clickBox5()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid6" onclick="clickBox6()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid7" onclick="clickBox7()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid8" onclick="clickBox8()"></div>
            <div class="grid-item" id="grid9" onclick="clickBox9()"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <button id="x-el" onclick="selectX()">X</button>
            <button id="o-el" onclick="selectO()">O</button>
        </div>
        <div class="score-container">
            <p id="playerscore">Player Score:</p>
            <p id="compscore">Computer Score:</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script>
        // Grab the elements
        let xBtn = document.getElementById('x-el')
        let oBtn = document.getElementById('o-el')
        let playerScoreDisplay = document.getElementById('playerscore')
        let compScoreDisplay = document.getElementById('compscore')
        let x = 'X'
        let o = 'O'

        // Grabbing individual boxes
        let box1 = document.getElementById('grid1');
        let box2 = document.getElementById('grid2');
        let box3 = document.getElementById('grid3');
        let box4 = document.getElementById('grid4');
        let box5 = document.getElementById('grid5');
        let box6 = document.getElementById('grid6');
        let box7 = document.getElementById('grid7');
        let box8 = document.getElementById('grid8');
        let box9 = document.getElementById('grid9');

/*
        let boxes = document.querySelectorAll("div.grid-item")
        */

        // Selecting x or o
        function selectX() {
            alert('You selected X!');
        }
        function selectO() {
            alert('You selected O!');
        }

        // Function for each box
        function clickBox1() {
            if (selectX) {
                box1.innerHTML = x;
            } else if (selectO) {
                box1.innerHTML = o;
            }
        }
        
        

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This line `if (selectX)` is always going to be true, because `selectX` is a function, so what you're saying is `if (this function exists)` then set it to x. And that function always exists. It's not checking if that was the function that was called or anything like that, just if the function is there.

Comment: @BrettEast how do I check if the function was called?

Comment: You do what swk23C8 said in their answer, you track it with another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to create a variable to save the user's choice and set it depending on whether or not they clicked on "x-el" or "o-el" like so below.

Also, loop through the boxes instead of creating a function for every single box.

```
    // user's choice      
    let myChoice
    // Selecting x or o
    function selectX() {
        alert('You selected X!');
        myChoice='X'
    }
    function selectO() {
        alert('You selected O!');
        myChoice='O'
    }

    // Function for each box
    function clickBox1() {
        if (myChoice==='X') {
            box1.innerHTML = x;
        } else if (myChoice==='O') {
            box1.innerHTML = o;
        }
    }
```